# Error bad substitution when scheduling script in crontab

Tags: linux, cron, substitution

```
a=$(iostat | awk 'FNR==4 {print $1}')
b=$(iostat | awk 'FNR==4 {print $2}')
c=$(iostat | awk 'FNR==4 {print $3}')
d=$(iostat | awk 'FNR==4 {print $4}')
e=$(iostat | awk 'FNR==4 {print $5}')
f=$(echo "scale=2;$a+$b+$c+$d+$e" | bc)
f=${f::-3}
echo $f >> /home/srikanth/tst
```

This is my code. I written it for cpu load. I wanted to schedule it in crontab for running it every minute. When i am executing it manually it working fine. but when i schedule it in crontab it is creating dead.letter with error

/home/srikanth/srk.sh: 7: /home/srikanth/srk.sh: Bad substitution

Can any one get me out of this

Thanks.....

Comment: SUGGESTION: Run your script with -x (verbose debug output) from cron to better understand what's going wrong.

Comment: I executed it manually with -x it is giving error  {./srk.sh: line 10: /home/srikanth/tst: Permission denied}. But "tst" file has 666 permissions

Comment: And which permissions does /home/srikanth has? Obviously the permissions don't match, also you haven't told us the group and owner of tst and under which user you are running your script. Please check every part of the path for the correct permissions.

Comment: owner & group both are srikanth. both script and file are under srikanth ownership. file has -rw-rw-rw- permissions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"*Bad substitution*" sounds like your shell can't handle your script. What [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) are you using? I assume cron runs your script with a different shell than the one you are using, e.g. dash instead of bash.

Try to add the following shebang to the start of your script and see if it fixes your problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
```